# Oracle pivot 2 columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table:

```
CA  C   P1  P2
--------------
CA1 C1  01  01
CA2 C2  02  02
CA1 C1  03  01
```

And I would like to obtain the below output:

```
CA  C   01_01   01_02   02_01   02_02   03_01   03_03
-----------------------------------------------------
CA1 C1      1       0       0       0       1       0
CA2 C2      0       0       0       1       0       0
```

This would be a double pivot showing the columns as P2_P1 with values as count of the occurrences in the original table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use tuples in the `for` and `in` clauses of pivot. Like this:

> ```
> with a(CA, C, P1, P2) as (
>   select 'CA1', 'C1', '01', '01' from dual union all
>   select 'CA2', 'C2', '02', '02' from dual union all
>   select 'CA1', 'C1', '03', '01' from dual
> )
> select *
> from a
> pivot(
>   count(*) for (p1, p2) in (
>     ('01', '01') as "01_01",
>     ('01', '02') as "01_02",
>     ('02', '01') as "02_01",
>     ('02', '02') as "02_02",
>     ('03', '01') as "03_01",
>     ('03', '02') as "03_02"
>   )
> )
> ```
>
> ```
> CA  | C  | 01_01 | 01_02 | 02_01 | 02_02 | 03_01 | 03_02
> :-- | :- | ----: | ----: | ----: | ----: | ----: | ----:
> CA1 | C1 |     1 |     0 |     0 |     0 |     1 |     0
> CA2 | C2 |     0 |     0 |     0 |     1 |     0 |     0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=de449e65248000b6550f6e6a4d07f79a)*

Answer (score 1):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select ca, c,
       sum(case when p1 = '01' and p2 = '01' then 1 else 0 end) as val_0101,
       sum(case when p1 = '01' and p2 = '02' then 1 else 0 end) as val_0102,
       sum(case when p1 = '02' and p2 = '01' then 1 else 0 end) as val_0201,
       sum(case when p1 = '02' and p2 = '02' then 1 else 0 end) as val_0202,
       sum(case when p1 = '03' and p2 = '01' then 1 else 0 end) as val_0301,
       sum(case when p1 = '03' and p2 = '02' then 1 else 0 end) as val_0302
from t
group by ca, c
```